# When an academic researcher receives a gift funding from an industry partner, does the academic researcher's university take a cut?

Tags: funding, industry, reference-request, gifts

When an academic researcher receives a gift funding from an industry partner, does the academic researcher's university take a cut, or does the academic researcher receives the entire gift funding?

If this is university and country dependent, I am mostly interested in the United States, and I'd be interested to have some survey (e.g., x % of universities % take a 20-30% commission, y % of universities % take no commission).

---

@Closevoters: according to [What is our stance regarding questions asking for survey of institution’s regulations?](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4501/452), the question is on-topic. Closing the question would prevent future readers to add surveys as an answer. For example, someone who work in the industry with many university partners might have a good idea of how often universities take commissions for gift fundings. Buffy's answer shows that one can give a good answer to the question, stating factors that may come into account.

In response to comments:

- [the expression "taking a cut" is neutral](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/214761/3023). I'm not trying to imply anything in my question.
- Definition of gift funding: see https://doresearch.stanford.edu/policies/research-policy-handbook/definitions-and-types-agreements/gift-vs-sponsored-projects-and-distinctions-other-forms-funding#anchor-1102 ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20190618162525/https://doresearch.stanford.edu/policies/research-policy-handbook/definitions-and-types-agreements/gift-vs-sponsored-projects-and-distinctions-other-forms-funding)) "A gift, on the other hand, is defined as any item of value given to the University by a donor who expects nothing significant of value in return". A gift isn't a grant or sponsored research project.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95107/discussion-on-question-by-franck-dernoncourt-when-an-academic-researcher-receive).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Than can depend on a lot of things. The answer is often yes, occasionally no.

The question may depend, in part, on what the university contributes to you as a researcher, including office space, lab space, RA support, whatever. It might also depend on whether it is the university that has to manage the grant and verify to the funder that the funds are properly spent - accounting for the funds and seeing that any necessary taxes are paid.

Universities have policies about these things and you should find out what those policies are in your case, but the answer is more likely that you and the university share the proceeds. The university "cut" might be quite a lot, actually.

And the characterization of it as a "gift" might be questioned or contested.